# AWS SageMaker TensorFlow RNN Training spending a ridiculous amount of time

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, tensorflow, keras, amazon-sagemaker

I have recently opened multiple training instances with the following script:

```
import os
import argparse
import json
from pickle import dump

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from sklearn.preprocessing import MinMaxScaler
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.sequence import TimeseriesGenerator

from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping


def create_model(length, layers):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(units=length, activation='relu', return_sequences=True, input_shape=(length, 1)))
    
    for layer in range(layers-2):
        model.add(LSTM(units=length - 5 * layer - 5, activation='relu', return_sequences=True))
    
    model.add(LSTM(units=length - 5 * layers, activation='relu'))

    model.add(Dense(1))

    model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
    
    return model

def train_model(train_gen, val_gen, epochs, length, layers, patience=-1):
    model = create_model(length, layers)
    if 0 <= patience < epochs:
        history = model.fit(train_gen, validation_data=val_gen, epochs=epochs, callbacks=[EarlyStopping(patience=patience)], verbose=1)
    else:
        history = model.fit(train_gen, validation_data=val_gen, epochs=epochs, verbose=1)
    
    return model, history

def interpolate(df):
    strdate = lambda date: pd.to_datetime(date, infer_datetime_format=True)
    df['Days'] = (strdate(df.index) - strdate(df.index[0])).days
    
    df.reset_index(inplace=True)
    for i in range(len(df) - 1):
        date, price, d = tuple(df.iloc[i].values)
        ndate, nprice, nd = tuple(df.iloc[i+1].values)
        differenceInd = nd - d
        if differenceInd != 1:
            rows = [[(strdate(date) + timedelta(days=dAdded)).date(), 
                   price + (nprice - price) * dAdded / differenceInd, 
                   d + dAdded] for dAdded in range(1, int(differenceInd))]
            interpolated = pd.DataFrame(data=rows, columns=df.columns)
            df = pd.concat([df.iloc[:i+1], interpolated, df.iloc[i+1:]], ignore_index=True)
    
    return df.drop(columns=['Days']).set_index('Date')

def preprocess_val(df, length):
    data = interpolate(df[['Open']])
    sc = MinMaxScaler()
    test_index = len(data) - length - 1
    X = data['Open'].round(3).values.astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 1)
    train = X[:test_index]
    test = X[test_index:]
    scaledtrain = sc.fit_transform(train)
    scaledtest = sc.transform(test)
    
    train_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(
        data=scaledtrain,
        targets=scaledtrain,
        length=length,
        batch_size=1)

    val_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(
        data=scaledtest,
        targets=scaledtest,
        length=length,
        batch_size=1)
    
    return train_gen, val_gen, sc

def preprocess(df, length):
    data = interpolate(df[['Open']])
    sc = MinMaxScaler()
    X = data['Open'].round(2).values.astype(np.float32).reshape(-1, 1)
    scaledtrain = sc.fit_transform(X)

    train_gen = TimeseriesGenerator(
        data=scaledtrain,
        targets=scaledtrain,
        length=length,
        batch_size=1)
    
    return train_gen, sc


def parse_args():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--model_dir', type=str)
    parser.add_argument('--sm-model-dir', type=str, default=os.environ.get('SM_MODEL_DIR'))
    parser.add_argument('--train', type=str, default=os.environ.get('SM_CHANNEL_TRAINING'))
    parser.add_argument('--hosts', type=list, default=json.loads(os.environ.get('SM_HOSTS')))
    parser.add_argument('--current-host', type=str, default=os.environ.get('SM_CURRENT_HOST'))
    parser.add_argument('--hyperparameters', type=dict, default=json.loads(os.environ.get('SM_HPS')))

    return parser.parse_known_args()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print('Loading Training Data')
    args, unknown = parse_args()
    hps = args.hyperparameters
    
    data = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(args.train, 'train.csv'), index_col='Date')
    
    print("Preprocessing Data")
    if "val" in hps.keys() and hps["val"]:
        train_gen, val_gen, scaler = preprocess_val(data, hps["length"])
    else:
        train_gen, scaler = preprocess(data, hps["length"])
        val_gen = None
    
    hps = {k: hps[k] for k in hps.keys() if k not in ("model_dir", "val")}
    
    print("Training Started")
    model, history = train_model(train_gen, val_gen, **hps)
    
    print("Training Complete. Saving Model...")
    dump(scaler, open('/opt/ml/model/scaler.pkl', 'wb'))
    model.save("/opt/ml/model/model.h5")
    pd.DataFrame(history).to_csv("/opt/ml/model/history.csv")
```

However, checking CloudWatch logs yields the following:

```
#015   1/1886 [..............................] - ETA: 3:37:34 - loss: 0.0472#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#010#0
```

x 10
Why is it taking so long to train?
The code used on the JupyterLab instance is:

```
import sagemaker
from sagemaker.tensorflow.estimator import TensorFlow
sess = sagemaker.Session(boto3.session.Session())
role = sagemaker.get_execution_role(sess)

inputs = sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput(s3_data=f's3://{bucket}/AirFrance/')

hyperparameters = dict(epochs=50,
                       length=60,
                       layers=4,
                       patience=-1,
                       val=False)

TensorflowEstimator = TensorFlow(entry_point='RNNTraining.py',
                                 role=role,
                                 instance_count=1,
                                 instance_type='ml.m5.xlarge',
                                 framework_version='2.3.0',
                                 py_version='py37',
                                 hyperparameters=hyperparameters)

TensorflowEstimator.fit(inputs, wait=False)
```

What could be the reason for this? The notebook instance being used has access to S3 and SageMaker ExecutionPolicy and it starts the training just fine.

Comment: What region is the S3 bucket and the Sagemaker notebook? Is this the same region as you?

Comment: @yudhiesh Yes it is

Comment: How big is the dataset?

Comment: @yudhiesh very small - one 100kb csv file.